# unfamiliar with the name of this ASP.NET/webform class

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

What is this thing called? I was hoping I could use something similar drop down as a "log in" box instead of having a whole page for logging in (which would contain text boxes and buttons).

[image]

Comment: You might call that a popover - though I don't think this sort of question is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Generally content that is "above" the main window content is known as a dialog box. These can be modal (only it can be interacted with) or non-modal. You've tagged this as Bootstrap, where the dialog boxes are called [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). When associated with a specific control they become "tooltips" or "popovers".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the actual element circled, this is simply an enhanced client-side tooltip to display messages to the user. This one in particular looks like it relies on [the jQuery UI library](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

That's generally going to be generated by the built-in jQuery validation that comes standard in some of the ASP.NET related templates. It uses a bit of client-side code to let the user know if what they are typing in is valid or not.

In reality, this is simply a just a form that will handle posting your information to the server and then routing the user to the appropriate location (and it could be handled with just a bit of HTML).

Comment: I think they're asking for "what is the general concept called where you show some information in an overlay above the content?"

Comment: Yes. I'm asking what that layout is generally called.

Comment: I've updated my response. The actual element itself is going to be a tooltip, assuming it appears when you hover over or focus on the textbox.